# MethodInvoker difference?

Tags: c#, winforms

What is the difference between this:

```
richTextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => richTextBox1.Clear()));
```

and this:

```
Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => richTextBox1.Clear()));
```

?

Is the first one better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second is calling `Invoke` on the implicit `this` reference, presumably for code inside of a `Form` or `UserControl`.

Given that, both are using an inherited version of the `Control.Invoke` method.  This means that the question simply becomes:

> What's the difference between calling `Invoke` on different Controls?

If the controls are bound to the same UI thread, nothing.

If they are bound to *different* UI threads, then you are invoking the method to run in completely different message loops being processed by completely different threads.  If you are accessing controls from a different UI thread within the delegate body, you'll get an exception (or worse, unexpected behavior).

Multiple UI threads are a terrible, terrible thing to have.  Don't use them if you can ever possibly avoid it.  Assuming you accept that advice, it means it doesn't matter which control you `Invoke` (so long as you don't invoke a `null` control).

Comment: Thank you. I decompiled the Invoke method of the framework:

 public object Invoke(Delegate method)
     {
        return this.Invoke(method, (object[]) null);
     }

It returns "this". So isn't the code faster if i use

 richTextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => richTextBox1.Clear()));

because this == richTextBox1

In the other case the thread would invoke the complete form (bigger object)

because this == form1

Comment: @PhazBlue The use of `this` in that context just means it's invoking a different overload of the same method.  If you don't provide a second argument (the parameters that will eventually get passed to the delegate you provided) then it passes a null object array.  There is *no* performance difference in that depending on the runtime type of `this`.  I can assure you that neither that, nor anything else, will result in any performance difference you could ever perceive in this comparison.

Answer (score 1):

In your second case, the invoke method is being called on the form ... in other words, this.Invoke().

This is inherited from the Control class.  Both should work as long as they are both on the UI thread.